# ASP.NET web app session timeout being ignored

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7.5, session-timeout

In my `web.config` I've set the session timeout to be 60 minutes using the following:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>
```

However, it seems that the session times out around 20 minutes anyhow.

Is there another timeout setting I should be using? I'm using .NET 4.5.2 and running in an application pool under IIS 7.5.

Comment: 20 minutes is the [IIS Default](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx). This page also has instructions on how to increase the session within IIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your IIS Settings

Select the Application Pool used by your site

Choose advanced settings

Under Process Model category increase the 'Idle Time-out' value

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it's working now. Do I even need `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>` in web.config anymore?

Comment: Glad that it helped ..by default mode is inProc and have 20 minutes timeout. i think we can remove it but i would test it before conclude !!

Comment: Don't remove or default value will apply